# How to take people from login to different page based on what they told abt themselves in signup in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so in my firebase i have 2 nodes Driver and customer and users have option to become one of them
in signup and after that in login i only ask for Email and Password.I want to know if there is a way to check in which node is tht mail attach to and take him  to respective page
(for eg Driver for those who chose driver)
This is my login page

```
public class Login_Page extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityLoginPageBinding binding;
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityLoginPageBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        button=findViewById(R.id.Googlelogin);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Login_Page.this,SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        progressdialog=new ProgressDialog(Login_Page.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Logging in");
        progressdialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        binding.Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressdialog.show();
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(binding.Email.getText().toString(),binding.Password.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                progressdialog.dismiss();
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(Login_Page.this,HomePage.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });
        if(auth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            Intent intent=new Intent(Login_Page.this,HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    }
}
```

Also I got how to do it in signup page so I will share my code in case there is any similarity btw them

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.deliveryapp.Models.Users;
import com.example.deliveryapp.databinding.ActivitySignUpBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    private Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        progressdialog=new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Creating Account");
        progressdialog.setMessage("pls wait while we create your account");
        binding.SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressdialog.show();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.Email.getText().toString()
                        ,binding.Password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressdialog.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Users user=new Users(binding.Username.getText().toString(),binding.Email.getText().toString(),binding.Password.getText().toString());
                            String id=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            String selectedOption  =  spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            database.getReference().child("Users").child(selectedOption).child(id).setValue(user);
                            if(selectedOption.contains("Driver")){
                                Intent intent=new Intent(SignUp.this,HomePage.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else{
                                Intent intent=new Intent(SignUp.this,Custhomepage.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve that.